# Why can't I access Jython access stdlib modules when called from tomcat?

Tags: jython, jython-2.7

I can take an application with the following code in it:

```
PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
interpreter.exec("import os");
interpreter.exec("import mylib");
```

Where the following is `resources/Lib/mylib/__init__.py`:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from . import myfriend as thing
import os

print("Yep, everything works")
```

and compile it using maven, producing a `my-app-with-dependencies.jar`

I can easily run  it with `java -jar my-app-with-depenendencies.jar` and it works just fine, hooray!

Here's where the sad part comes in. I can put this *exact same code* inside a Spring handler:

```
@RequestMapping("/doesnotwork")
public @ResponseBody String sadness() {
    PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
    interpreter.exec("import os");
    interpreter.exec("import mylib");  

    return "Quoth the Java, nevermore";
}
```

and magically this *no longer works*. Not one little bit.

I *can* however move my file from `resources/Lib/` to `webapp/WEB-INF/lib/Lib/` and `import mylib` works. But within `mylib` I can no longer import from `__future__` or `os`. I can `import sys`, and my sys.path looks like this:

```
['/path/to/my/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/Lib', '__classpath__', '__pyclasspath__/']
```

My `sys.path_importer_cache` looks like this:

```
{'__classpath__': <type 'org.python.core.JavaImporter'>,
 '/path/to/my/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/Lib': None, 
 '/path/to/my/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/Lib/mylib': None, 
 '__pyclasspath__/': <ClasspathPyImporter object at 0x2>}
```

What am I doing wrong that I can't import the stdlib? `/path/to/my/webapp/WEB-INF/lib` contains both `jython-2.7-b1.jar` and `jython-standalone-2.7-b1.jar`. I've even tried inserting those jar files into my path and *still* no dice.

I can import *java* classes from .jar files present in the folder, except for ones found in the jython .jars. For instance, inside `jython-2.7-b1.jar` are `org/python/apache/xml/serialize/Serializer.class`. I can import `org.python` but there only exists `org.python.__name__`.

Comment: This issue also appears to [affect Moneydance](https://bitbucket.org/infinitekind/moneydance_open/issues/3/unable-to-import-stdlib-modules).